# material-ui Drawer above sidebar

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am developing a web page with react typescript  and material-ui
material-ui Drawer takes the all screen width but instead I want to make it have the width of the screen - sidebar
like the example in the image
how can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to reference it's kinda hard to give you an accurate answer.

I suggest you start by giving the Siderbar a `width` of `20vw`, and the Drawer a `width` of `80vw`. If that's not helping, try setting the `max-width` property as well, to prevent it from extending above what you like.

The `20vw` and `80vw` could be any value you like, that fits your design.